# Access Cloudflare Worker from local environments

Tags: microservices, cloudflare, worker

I've setup a functional Cloudflare Worker via its route and domain and am using the Worker playground and the quick editor to avoid a deployment.

**However, when developing locally I cannot make a request to the worker and get a CORs error.**

I’ve read all the docs and implemented most CF security features within Zero Trust. However, nothing is getting us access to our deployed Worker due to strict CORs rules. (which we want)

1. On my machine I am routing through WARP and it is configured for my
   team name.
2. I have installed and configured a root access certificate, perhaps
   not applicable to this issue.
3. I have also tried to manually auth by visiting the worker URL and
   getting a login code emailed to me. Perhaps CF Access is not related
   to Workers?

We need clarification because the docs do not clearly explain the flow for access to Worker URLs when working on localhost.

[Community question here.](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/configuring-to-allow-local-development-to-access-cf-workers/435680)

**How do we develop apps with Workers and strict CORs by authenticating a computer or user?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Transform Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/) for set/remove/update CORS.
It should work for you, because according to traffic sequence diagram header modifications performs before workers. [image]